# Don't see the jrebel.log

Tags: logging, intellij-idea, jrebel

JRebel settings:
[image]

[image]

C:\JRebel-5.0:

```
16.07.2012  13:29    <DIR>          .
16.07.2012  13:29    <DIR>          ..
16.07.2012  04:23            71 264 3rd-party-licenses.txt
16.07.2012  05:04    <DIR>          bin
16.07.2012  04:08            48 511 Changelog.txt
16.07.2012  05:04    <DIR>          doc
16.07.2012  04:18             1 150 jrebel.ico
16.07.2012  13:29                20 jrebel.info
16.07.2012  13:29                20 jrebel.info.tmp
16.07.2012  04:23         4 398 694 jrebel.jar
16.07.2012  05:05            23 977 jrebel.plugininfo
16.07.2012  04:23               685 jrebel.png
16.07.2012  04:23            29 499 License.txt
16.07.2012  13:29               123 licensing.info
16.07.2012  04:23               188 readme.txt
16.07.2012  04:23               237 ZeroTurnaround.url
```

c:\Users\Abbas\.IntelliJIdea11\config\plugins\jr-ide-idea\lib\jrebel:

```
16.07.2012  12:09    <DIR>          .
16.07.2012  12:09    <DIR>          ..
16.07.2012  04:59            71 264 3rd-party-licenses.txt
16.07.2012  04:59    <DIR>          bin
16.07.2012  04:59            48 511 Changelog.txt
16.07.2012  04:59    <DIR>          conf
16.07.2012  04:59    <DIR>          doc
16.07.2012  04:59    <DIR>          extras
16.07.2012  04:59             1 150 jrebel.ico
16.07.2012  04:23         4 398 694 jrebel.jar
16.07.2012  12:09            23 977 jrebel.plugininfo
16.07.2012  04:59               685 jrebel.png
16.07.2012  04:59            29 499 License.txt
16.07.2012  05:03               156 licensing.info
16.07.2012  04:59               188 readme.txt
16.07.2012  04:59               237 ZeroTurnaround.url
```

Run/Debug Configuration:
[image]

[image]

[image]

After Run Jrebel with 'JBoss 4.2.3 GA Local', I don't see the Jrebel messages:

```
C:\JBOSS\jboss-portal-2.7.2\bin\run-jrebel.cmd -c default
[2012-07-16 01:55:53,831] Artifact app-ear:ear: Server is not connected. Press 'Deploy' to start deployment.
[2012-07-16 01:55:53,832] Artifact my-portlet:war: Server is not connected. Press 'Deploy' to start deployment.
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: C:\JBOSS\jboss-portal-2.7.2

  JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\java

  JAVA_OPTS: -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n -Dhttp.proxyHost=188.173.32.78 -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 -DproxySet=true -Dprogram.name=run.bat -server -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000

  CLASSPATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\lib\tools.jar;C:\JBOSS\jboss-portal-2.7.2\bin\run.jar

===============================================================================

Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8787
13:55:54,459 INFO  [Server] Starting JBoss (MX MicroKernel)...
13:55:54,462 INFO  [Server] Release ID: JBoss [Trinity] 4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181417)
13:55:54,464 INFO  [Server] Home Dir: C:\JBOSS\jboss-portal-2.7.2
13:55:54,464 INFO  [Server] Home URL: file:/C:/JBOSS/jboss-portal-2.7.2/
13:55:54,465 INFO  [Server] Patch URL: null
13:55:54,466 INFO  [Server] Server Name: default
13:55:54,466 INFO  [Server] Server Home Dir: C:\JBOSS\jboss-portal-2.7.2\server\default
13:55:54,466 INFO  [Server] Server Home URL: file:/C:/JBOSS/jboss-portal-2.7.2/server/default/
13:55:54,467 INFO  [Server] Server Log Dir: C:\JBOSS\jboss-portal-2.7.2\server\default\log
13:55:54,467 INFO  [Server] Server Temp Dir: C:\JBOSS\jboss-portal-2.7.2\server\default\tmp
13:55:54,467 INFO  [Server] Root Deployment Filename: jboss-service.xml
13:55:55,092 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version: 1.6.0_25,Sun Microsystems Inc.
13:55:55,093 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 20.0-b11,Sun Microsystems Inc.
13:55:55,093 INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Windows 7 6.1,amd64
13:55:56,147 INFO  [Server] Core system initialized
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in 5.0. Add -Drebel.log=true to VM arguments and the log will be written to {user.home}/.jrebel/jrebel.log

And you better just start with "Run with JRebel" button instead of replacing the startup script.